# How to read class name of a html element in php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a project in php in which the class name will be read and transformed into variable and will set background of that specific color mentioned in the class. for eg, if I type `<div class="#999">` , I should get the background color `#999`of the element (div).
I did everything fine but having trouble to get the element's class, pls help me out how to get the class of the element.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do it in javascript using document selectors using the method `document.getelementbyid().classname`

Comment: `the class name will be read ... and will set background of that specific color mentioned in the class`...this sounds like what CSS is for. Not sure where PHP would be involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the data- attribute and not the class name.
In your case I would add `data-bg="#999"` and then read it in JS and set the background color.

[Here is some documentation for data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

container.style.backgroundColor = container.dataset.bg;
```

```html
<div id="container" data-bg="#999">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Sure, but why not just set a CSS style using this colour to begin with instead of having a class name which is actually a colour? Can't see why JavaScript would be necessary.

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought, but I don't know why it didn't work for me. There is a section about that on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr()#color_value), so yes CSS would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for CSS, rather than PHP or even JavaScript.

You can either

a) set an inline style on the element itself defining the background colour (this is simple and quick but not the most maintainable or flexible in the long run):

```html
<div style="background-color:#999">Div Contents Here</div>
```

OR

b) define a CSS class which has a rule setting the background colour for all elements which have that class:

```css
.classA {
  background-color:#999;
}
```

```html
<div class="classA">Div Contents Here</div>
```

This seems like the most efficient way to define a background colour. If you need to vary which colour the div is given, define multiple classes which have different background colours, and get your PHP to output a different class name for the div, depending on your rules.

(N.B. Your question wasn't 100% clear so if I've misunderstood what you mean, then please let me know and I can update the answer.)